# Python console input output needs threading?

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets, console, telnet

I've found a Python telnet file, which works fine (at [binary tides](http://www.binarytides.com/code-telnet-client-sockets-python/)) but I'm hoping to (learn to) implement control over the input area such that I have shell like history and editing of the input line, uninterrupted by the feed from the telnet server I'm logged into.

I've seen some posts on this, would I be right to think that I need to learn threading so that I can simultaneously watch the server, the input line and handle the *division* of the console area, to do this? Similar to the discussion of threads/sockets here ([SO separate threads for sockets..](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1748808/separate-threads-for-socket-input-and-output)) except that is for Java and I'm trying to study Python.

Or perhaps [SO TKinter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9159033/output-from-python-console) is what I should put in my study list..?

EDIT: I should mention that I hope to move to GUI presentation eventually for my small projects but for this one I'm happy to use the console...I figured it might be a smaller step (learning curve).