# Python TKinter binding to enter key

Tags: python, tkinter, user-input

I've tried applying the various examples given in several other SO Question Answers but it's eluding me.

My goal is to be able to send a line of text to a telnet server when "enter" is pressed. My steps toward that are to simply send the last line (since the previous "enter" was pressed) to the output panel.

I've gotten a clumsy set of windows and seem to have attached Text boxes to them, but when I apply any binding type code I end up being unable to write in the input text box. When I remove the binding code I can at least type text into either text box.

This issue relates back to my other [query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29724981/python-console-input-output-needs-threading), which is why I am now trying to absorb GUI coding.

The code, of which the skeleton came from the tut' info at [Thinking in Tkinter](http://www.ferg.org/thinking_in_tkinter/all_programs.html)

EDIT: Code lines changed re: Tiger's comments

```
from Tkinter import *

class MyApp:
    def __init__(self, parent):

        #------ constants for controlling layout of buttons ------
        button_width = 15
        button_padx = "2m"
        button_pady = "1m"
        buttons_frame_padx =  "3m"
        buttons_frame_pady =  "0m"
        buttons_frame_ipadx = "3m"
        buttons_frame_ipady = "0m"
        # -------------- end button constants ----------------

        # First declare ORIGINAL Window area
        self.myParent = parent
        self.myParent.geometry("640x400")

        # Layer ONE
        ### Our First layer/frame is called frameLayerOne
        self.frameLayerOne = Frame(parent, bg="green")
        self.frameLayerOne.pack(expand=YES, fill=BOTH)

        ### We will stack vertically inside frameLayerOne.
        ### Inside frameLayerOne, we will create 
        ### a menu_frame, then a sub frame into which we will
        ### put an output_frame and an input_frame.

        # Layer TWO
        # MENU FRAME - Layer Two
        self.menu_frame = Frame(self.frameLayerOne, borderwidth=5,  relief=RIDGE, bg="cyan")
        self.menu_frame.pack(side=TOP, expand=NO,  padx=0, pady=0, ipadx=0, ipady=0, fill=X)

        MessageMenuFrame="Menu frame.\n"
        # Label(self.menu_frame, text=MessageMenuFrame, justify=LEFT).pack(side=TOP, anchor=W)

        # buttons frame
        self.buttons_frame = Frame(self.menu_frame) # , bg="red"
        self.buttons_frame.pack(side=TOP,
            ipadx=buttons_frame_ipadx,
            ipady=buttons_frame_ipady,
            padx=buttons_frame_padx,
            pady=buttons_frame_pady,)

        # now we add the buttons to the buttons_frame
        self.button1 = Button(self.buttons_frame, command=self.button1Click)
        self.button1.configure(text="CONNECT", background= "green")
        self.button1.focus_force()
        self.button1.configure(width=button_width,
            padx=button_padx,
            pady=button_pady)

        self.button1.pack(side=LEFT)
        self.button1.bind("<Return>", self.button1Click_a)

        self.button2 = Button(self.buttons_frame, command=self.button2Click)
        self.button2.configure(text="QUIT", background="red")
        self.button2.configure(width=button_width,
            padx=button_padx,
            pady=button_pady)

        self.button2.pack(side=RIGHT)
        self.button2.bind("<Return>", self.button2Click_a)

        # SUB FRAME - Layer Two
        self.sub_frame = Frame(self.frameLayerOne) # , bg="red"
        self.sub_frame.pack(side=BOTTOM, expand=YES,  padx=0, pady=0, ipadx=0, ipady=0, fill=BOTH)

        # Layer THREE
        # INPUT FRAME - Layer Three
        self.input_frame = Frame(self.sub_frame, borderwidth=5,  relief=RIDGE, bg="black")
        self.input_frame.pack(side=BOTTOM, expand=NO,  padx=0, pady=0, ipadx=0, ipady=0, fill=X)

        # Text widget for user input to send to server
        self.InputText = Text(self.input_frame, height=4, bg="black", fg="green")
        self.InputText.pack()
        self.InputText.insert(END, "User input here")

        # Moded these two lines on Tiger's advice
        self.input_frame.bindtags(('.input_frame','input_frame','post-class-bindings', '.', 'all'))
        self.input_frame.bind_class('<Return>', self.return_key)

        # OUTPUT FRAME - Layer Three
        self.output_frame = Frame(self.sub_frame, borderwidth=5,  relief=RIDGE, bg="blue")
        self.output_frame.pack(side=BOTTOM, expand=YES,  padx=0, pady=0, ipadx=5, ipady=25, fill=BOTH)

        # Text widget for output from code and server
        self.OutputText = Text(self.output_frame, bg="black", fg="green")
        self.OutputText.pack()
        self.OutputText.insert(END, "server and code output here")


    def return_key(self, event):
        text = "you pressed Return"
        self.InputText.insert(END, text)

    def button1Click(self):
        if self.button1["background"] == "green":
            self.button1["background"] = "yellow"
        else:
            self.button1["background"] = "green"

    def button1Click_a(self, event):
        self.button1Click()


    def button2Click(self):
        self.myParent.destroy()


    def button2Click_a(self, event):
        self.button2Click()


root = Tk()
myapp = MyApp(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've made some changes to your code, labeling the comments `T3` for visibility. This allows you to use Return on the `Buttons` and `Text` field, with the "connect" button "rescuing" focus, in effect.

```
from Tkinter import *

class MyApp:
    def __init__(self, parent):

        #------ constants for controlling layout of buttons ------
        button_width = 15
        button_padx = "2m"
        button_pady = "1m"
        buttons_frame_padx =  "3m"
        buttons_frame_pady =  "0m"
        buttons_frame_ipadx = "3m"
        buttons_frame_ipady = "0m"
        # -------------- end button constants ----------------

        # First declare ORIGINAL Window area
        self.myParent = parent
        self.myParent.geometry("640x400")

        # Layer ONE
        ### Our First layer/frame is called frameLayerOne
        self.frameLayerOne = Frame(parent, bg="green")
        self.frameLayerOne.pack(expand=YES, fill=BOTH)

        ### We will stack vertically inside frameLayerOne.
        ### Inside frameLayerOne, we will create 
        ### a menu_frame, then a sub frame into which we will
        ### put an output_frame and an input_frame.

        # Layer TWO
        # MENU FRAME - Layer Two
        self.menu_frame = Frame(self.frameLayerOne, borderwidth=5,  relief=RIDGE, bg="cyan")
        self.menu_frame.pack(side=TOP, expand=NO,  padx=0, pady=0, ipadx=0, ipady=0, fill=X)

        MessageMenuFrame="Menu frame.\n"
        # Label(self.menu_frame, text=MessageMenuFrame, justify=LEFT).pack(side=TOP, anchor=W)

        # buttons frame
        self.buttons_frame = Frame(self.menu_frame) # , bg="red"
        self.buttons_frame.pack(side=TOP,
            ipadx=buttons_frame_ipadx,
            ipady=buttons_frame_ipady,
            padx=buttons_frame_padx,
            pady=buttons_frame_pady,)

        # now we add the buttons to the buttons_frame
        self.button1 = Button(self.buttons_frame, command=self.button1Click)
        self.button1.configure(text="CONNECT", background= "green")
        self.button1.focus_force()
        self.button1.configure(width=button_width,
            padx=button_padx,
            pady=button_pady)

        self.button1.pack(side=LEFT)
        # T3 - bound to regular button1Click
        self.button1.bind("<Return>", self.button1Click)

        self.button2 = Button(self.buttons_frame, command=self.button2Click)
        self.button2.configure(text="QUIT", background="red")
        self.button2.configure(width=button_width,
            padx=button_padx,
            pady=button_pady)

        self.button2.pack(side=RIGHT)
        # T3 - bound to regular button2Click
        self.button2.bind("<Return>", self.button2Click)

        # SUB FRAME - Layer Two
        self.sub_frame = Frame(self.frameLayerOne) # , bg="red"
        self.sub_frame.pack(side=BOTTOM, expand=YES,  padx=0, pady=0, ipadx=0, ipady=0, fill=BOTH)

        # Layer THREE
        # INPUT FRAME - Layer Three
        self.input_frame = Frame(self.sub_frame, borderwidth=5,  relief=RIDGE, bg="black")
        self.input_frame.pack(side=BOTTOM, expand=NO,  padx=0, pady=0, ipadx=0, ipady=0, fill=X)

        # Text widget for user input to send to server
        self.InputText = Text(self.input_frame, height=4, bg="black", fg="green")
        self.InputText.pack()
        self.InputText.insert(END, "User input here")

        self.InputText.bind('<Return>', self.return_key)

        # OUTPUT FRAME - Layer Three
        self.output_frame = Frame(self.sub_frame, borderwidth=5,  relief=RIDGE, bg="blue")
        self.output_frame.pack(side=BOTTOM, expand=YES,  padx=0, pady=0, ipadx=5, ipady=25, fill=BOTH)

        # Text widget for output from code and server
        self.OutputText = Text(self.output_frame, bg="black", fg="green")
        self.OutputText.pack()
        self.OutputText.insert(END, "server and code output here")


    def return_key(self, event):
        text = "you pressed Return"
        self.InputText.insert(END, text)

    def button1Click(self, event=None): # T3 - give it a default event of None
        if self.button1["background"] == "green":
            self.button1["background"] = "yellow"
        else:
            self.button1["background"] = "green"
        self.button1.focus_set() # T3 - set focus to this button so Return works

    def button2Click(self, event=None): # T3 - give it a default event of None
        self.myParent.destroy()

root = Tk()
myapp = MyApp(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks for the input. I tried it, and now I can at least enter text in the InputText box now, but now event is being triggered, that I can see..

Comment: sorry, **no** event, that I can see. I placed a myParentdestroy() in the function called (returnkey()) but bupkis, =/

Comment: You still have some issues where you're binding keypresses to `Button` widgets, and you have the same keypress bound to multiple functions (bound to both the "switch connect button color" function and the "quit" function). Bind it to one command, such as `button1Click`, to one widget, such as `self.myParent`. Then, whenever the user presses the Return key, the "connect" button will switch colors. If you want to bind a keypress to the exit function, try binding `<Esc>` to `self.myParent`.

Comment: ok ... the original tut' I got that from was showing how focus can be on a button such that _return_ will 'click' the button... and I'm guessing, as always but, if such functionality were to be kept I can't bind it to the parent frame or it becomes ambiguous which button is being 'clicked' ... no ?

Comment: Looks like the `Button` bindings work - they just have to have focus (faint outline). However, if you bind `self.InputText.bind('<Return>', self.return_key)`, you can type and see the text added to the box when you press Return, but you can't change the focus once it's in the Text widget. I will edit my answer with some modifications.

Comment: Many thanks, it's catching the bind now and output appearing in the text box (I changed to output frame) I can now pursue sending the text elsewhere - I'll have to study this stuff _deeply_ try to figure/remember it. **Thank you**